# Configure MSSQL with php 7

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I am having issues in installing MSSQL in my php library.

I am getting below error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\img\test.php:7 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\img\test.php(7):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=D...', '', '') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\img\test.php on line 7

I have added below dll files as per the R&D but still I am not able to run mssql.
I am working with my local system and installed SQL server 2012 and MS SQL manager 
I have created a database name THL with sone table 
I added server name (local)\sqlexpress but it did'nt worked so I changed it to DESKTOP-DDOS0G1\sqlexpress still it is not working.

[image]

My connection code is below

```
<?php
$serverName = 'DESKTOP-DDOS0G1\sqlexpress';
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=DHL", "", "");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
if(!$conn) {
    echo 'Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}else
{
    echo 'connected';
}
?>
```

Please suggest what things I have missed in this process. I have also installed ODBC.

Comment: See updated answer. It is possible to mix PDO and not PDO approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanations:**

You need to install or configure PHP Driver for SQL Server (`sqlsrv` and/or `pdo_sqlsrv` PHP extension).

- Check Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server [Support Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017) and download appropriate version of this driver. If you use PHP 7 or later, you should choose version 4.0, 4.3, 5.2 or 5.3 (32-bit or 64-bit also depends on PHP version).
- Check [System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017) for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server. An appropriate ODBC driver installation is also required.
- [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017) PHP Driver for SQL Server as PHP extension.

Check the configuration with `<?php phpinfo();?>`. There should be a section with name `pdo_sqlsrv` (if you use PDO) and/or `sqlsrv` (without PDO).

**Examples:**

With PDO:

```
<?php
$serverName = 'DESKTOP-DDOS0G1\sqlexpress';
try
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=DHL", "", "");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}   
?>
```

Without PDO:

```
<?php
$serverName = 'DESKTOP-DDOS0G1\sqlexpress';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database" => "DHL"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $cinfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
?>
```